# "Но в наше время, реальные игрушки уже не привлекают внимания". Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Но в наше время, реальные игрушки уже не привлекают внимания

Comment: А в чём её необходимость?

Comment: Это случаем не перевод из материалов комп. игры? В английском при таком порядке слов нужна запятая, в русском это было бы ошибкой.

Comment: Заезженное определение РЕАЛЬНОЕ хорошо бы хоть изредка разбавлять НЕ ВИРТУАЛЬНЫМ, ОБЫЧНЫМ, ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНЫМ, НАТУРАЛЬНЫМ.

Answer (score 3):

**Но в наше время // реальные игрушки уже не привлекают внимания.**

В начале предложения расположен **детерминант**, то есть второстепенный член, отнесенный ко всему предложению. Запятой он не выделяется (для этого нет грамматического основания), но при достаточном распространении после него делается произносительная пауза, которую по ошибке иногда обозначают запятой.

В данном предложении  эта пауза может быть увеличена, если логическим ударением выделить слово "наше".

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое))